# How do I get this page programatically?

Tags: python, ajax, html, fetch

Here is the page [THE LINK TO LYRICS SITE](http://www.lyricsplugin.com/wmplayer03/plugin/?artist=aerosmith&title=crazy)

If I use normal method, all I get is the "http://lyricsvip.com" and not the lyrics.

Comment: What is "the normal method"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's because the lyrics are loaded by Javascript and the 'normal' method doesn't execute Javascript when you try to scrape the page.

Seems like you're out of luck unfortunately, unless you manage to execute the Javascript-method found in the source:

```
<body onload="javascript:getContent('aerosmith', 'crazy', '1281384888', '0475352e376cf1c3906afd8ec1b8ac70')">
```

Which I'm pretty sure you wont be able to, since it's probably put there to prevent just that.. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do this, it *is* possible. You will need to control something like Gecko (using e.g. [pywebkigtk](http://code.google.com/p/pywebkitgtk/)) to open the web page up in a full browser that can execute JS, and then get the source code from that once it's finished rendering.

However, you won't be able to do it with any less than that. If you look at the Javascript source, you'll see that it just makes an AJAX POST request to `content.php`:

```
var url = "content.php?artist=" + artist + "&title=" + title + "&time=" + time + "&check=" + check;
```

with `check`, probably a hashed session ID. This is undoubtedly there to stop people doing exactly what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

if you're on Windows, you could use [PAMIE](http://pamie.sourceforge.net/) to drive a browser....